# "Cannot Use Import Outside of a Module" in VS Code Notebook Extension

Tags: webpack, vscode-extensions, tsc

I'm learning how to use VS Code Notebook API. I'm trying to build a *single extension* that contributes to notebooks and notebook renderers. While debugging the extension, I'm getting "Cannot Use Import Outside of a Module" error which is, as I suppose, connected with TSC/Webpack magic.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Create a "New Notebook Renderer (TypeScript)" extension

```
yo code --extensionType=notebook
```

2. Open `src/extension/extension.ts`
3. Add `import { TextEncoder } from 'util';`
4. Add `new TextEncoder();` in `activate` function body
5. Click "Start Debugging"

[image]

As I understand, the error is caused by

```
import{createRequire as e}from"module";
```

which gets generated in `out/extension/extension.js` when there is a reference to a class from another module.

### My Attempt to Solve the Problem

1. Open `webpack.config.js`
2. Remove

```
experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
},
```

2. Replace

```
makeConfig(argv, { entry: './src/client/index.ts', out: './out/client/index.js', target: 'web', library: 'module' }),
```

with

```
makeConfig(argv, { entry: './src/client/index.ts', out: './out/client/index.js', target: 'web', library: 'commonjs' }),
```

3. Run `npm run compile`
4. Click "Start Debugging"

The previous error should disappear. Now there is another one

[image]

My further attempts to include `var exports = {};` somewhere in build artifacts cause even more problems.

Do you know how to fix the error? I don't want to split the extension into two separate parts.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that VS Extensions use Node.js and that requires (at least currently) code to be CommonJS. By adding an `import` statement, you are trying to use ESM syntax (CommonJS uses `require`). You have now three options to solve this:

1. Use `require` instead of `import`.
2. Use [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).
3. Make your extension using ESM and use a bundler like webpack or esbuild to generate a CJS bundle for your extension.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to configure TypeScript and Webpack myself and it have solved the issue.

Here is the TypeScript configuration for renderer part.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES2019",
    "lib": ["ES2019", "DOM"],
    "types": ["webpack-env", "vscode-notebook-renderer"],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "../../dist/client",
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "references": []
}
```

Here is the TypeScript configuration for rest of the notebook.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES2019",
    "lib": ["ES2019"],
    "types": ["node"],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "../../dist/extension"
  },
  "references": []
}
```

And here is the Webpack configuration.

```js
// @ts-check

'use strict';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

/**
 * @type {webpack.Configuration}
 */
const extensionConfig = {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'none',
  entry: './src/extension/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'extension'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
  },
  externals: {
    vscode: 'commonjs vscode'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
  infrastructureLogging: {
    level: 'log',
  },
};

/**
 * @type {webpack.Configuration}
 */
const clientConfig = {
  target: 'web',
  mode: 'none',
  entry: './src/client/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'client'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    publicPath: '',
    libraryTarget: 'module'
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          configFile: path.join('./src/client', 'tsconfig.json'),
          transpileOnly: true,
          compilerOptions: {
            noEmit: false,
          },
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    vscode: 'commonjs vscode'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __webpack_relative_entrypoint_to_root__: JSON.stringify(
        path.posix.relative(path.posix.dirname(`/index.js`), '/'),
      ),
      scriptUrl: 'import.meta.url',
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  infrastructureLogging: {
    level: 'log',
  },
};

module.exports = [
  extensionConfig,
  clientConfig,
];
```